# Change precacheManifest folder in workbox-webpack-plugin

Tags: workbox

For current version in 3.0, workbox will generate manifest file with filename `precache-manifest.[hash].js`
But this file will follow our `publicPath` in webpack.
So in my case it will produce file in folder `/dist/precache-manifest.[hash].js`.

Question:

Is there any way to change this folder from workbox config, let say I want put this file in `dist/static/precache-manifest.[hash].js`.

Very thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed by Workbox Team in https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1411
This already done, but still waiting for next workbox release date to be live.

Here the PR : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/pull/1403
Hope help others have same problem.